# Visual Studio Code se cierra después de un rato simulando

Tags: python, vscode, powershell, visual

Estoy intentando ejecutar un código de Python en Visual Studio Code. Al cabo de un rato ocurren dos problemas indistintamente: se cierra Visual Studio Code y me aparece el aviso de Windows de: "Powershell dejó de funcionar. El programa dejó de funcionar correctamente por un problema. Windows cerrará ..."; o bien se deja de ejecutar el programa sin más como si hubiera terminado (y no lo ha hecho ya que al final me debería devolver unas gráficas). No creo que sea un problema del código ya que al simular menos tiempo, el programa se ejecuta perfectamente. Al principio introduces por pantalla el tiempo que deseas simular, el error aparece cuando aumento el tamaño de la simulación (simulando más tiempo, por ejemplo).

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Además de traducir tu pregunta, muestra un [repro] del código en cuestión.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @padaleiana el código es bastante largo y se compone de varios archivos por lo que se me hace complicado subirlo. No creo que sea un problema del código ya que al simular menos tiempo, el programa se ejecuta perfectamente. Al principio introduces por pantalla el tiempo que deseas simular, el caso es cuando aumento el tamaño de la simulación (simulando más tiempo, por ejemplo) al cabo de un rato el código en ejecución se cierra automáticamente y me aparece el aviso de Windows de: "Powershell dejó de funcionar. El programa dejó de funcionar correctamente por un problema. Windows cerrará ..."

Comment: @padaleiana perfecto, ya he traducido la pregunta. Ahora que entiendes el problema, ¿se te ocurre alguna solución? Código no puedo proporcionar pero como digo no es problema del mismo ya que funciona correctamente al simular cortos periodos temporales.

Comment: La cuestión es que pueden ser múltiples cosas. Si no se muestra un [repro], es difícil responder. No es tirar ideas al azar: es responder al problema _específico_.

Comment: @padaleiana perfecto, muchas gracias!!!